# How to send(broadcast) data from android device to all other participant android device

Tags: android

Initially I thought socket.io would be good. But I failed miserable, unable to get hold of nodejs. Is there something which I can code in java. I think its websocket but I am not clear about it. Please provide me some suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cloud messaging service. I would suggest http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/android-sdk.html

Comment: @thetatheta maybe you can. But bear in mind that there are lots of tutorials on the web. So if you question is "I tried it with websockets and it didn't work", then it's too broad and you won't get any answer here.

Comment: you misunderstood my point. I tried socket.io it worked but when i tried to implement it in android i failed. As it was new to me I switched to Websocket and I now I know how to do it using websocket.

Comment: @thetatheta then google it, implement a solution and if something's wrong, post relevant source codes and error messages.

Comment: Plz see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856950/i-have-websocket-server-endpoint-and-i-need-websocket-client-to-listen-for-any-b